# Android ViewModel recreates on configuration change

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-lifecycle

I got one Activity and few fragments.

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    performInjection();
    performDataBinding();
}

private void performDataBinding() {
    viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, setLayoutId());
    this.viewModel = viewModel == null ? onCreateViewModel() : viewModel;
    viewDataBinding.setVariable(setBindingVariable(), viewModel);
    viewDataBinding.executePendingBindings();
}
@Override
public MainViewModel onCreateViewModel() {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel.class);
}
```

DI injection:

```
@Provides
ViewModelProvider.Factory mainViewModelProvider(MainViewModel mainViewModel) {
    return new ViewModelProviderFactory<>(mainViewModel);
}
```

Fragment code:

```
@Override
public BalanceViewModel setViewModel() {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(BalanceViewModel.class);
}
```

And log when I change orientation:

```
D/BalanceViewModel: Recreation / constructor
D/MainViewModel: Recreation / constructor
D/BalanceViewModel: Recreation / constructor
D/BalanceViewModel: Recreation / onCleared
```

So, my qestion is why viewModels calls constructor every time I change orientation? Does it connected with DI or not?

Comment: found solution to this?